# Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS - No option to try without installing

Tags: boot, lubuntu

I've got a very old PC (2002 - 32 bits) and I would like to switch it to Linux, it is far too slow to run Windows.
I've downloaded Lubuntu 16.04 LTS, created proper USB boot key and try it on a recent PC first.
PC starts with some errors appearing briefly then start with choice language (I've selected French).
But then, in the list offered, there is not the option to try Lubuntu without installing; First option is always "install Lubuntu".
I think I've used Lubuntu **Alternate** level 16.04.1 LTS (I am not in front of the proper PC right now). Could this be the problem?
Should I use **desktop** version instead (I have downloaded 16.04.4 LTS)? 
Or did I miss something?
Please help.

Comment: The alternate installer is 'only' an installer. It needs less computer power and less RAM, so it can be a good option in a very old computer. But if you want to try a live system, you need the desktop iso file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in that case you should get the *Desktop* edition. You can always find the currently supported [Lubuntu releases on its official web page](https://lubuntu.net/downloads/), though you need to scroll down a bit for the 16.04 release.

Answer (score 2):

I have quickly tested this and yes, the alternate ISO is a straight installer, only the desktop ISO has the live option.